# How to get the full filename from ProjectItems?

Tags: c#, envdte, projectitem

My code, which has been working right on another computer fails at `FullPath` and `FileName` points. The error is:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'FullPath' and no extension method 'FullPath' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.

The code is :

```
var sftp = new Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp(direction);
sftp.Connect();
foreach( var fileName in  sftp.GetFileList(Properties.Settings.Default.DirectorioFtp) )
{
    byte[] fichero;
    sftp.Get(fileName.FullPath, out fichero);

    var enc = new UTF7Encoding();
    string str = enc.GetString(fichero);

    ProcessFile(fileName.Filename, str);
}
```

I have  loaded `Tamir.SharpSSh` succesfully, but I don't know if another library is needed or how to make filename of the necessary type.

Comment: What does `GetFileList` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code for `Tamir.SharpSSH.Sftp` at http://sourceforge.net/p/sharpssh/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/SharpSSH/Sftp.cs says that `GetFileList` returns an `ArrayList` of `String`s (as `Object`s, because `ArrayList` is not a "generic" collection), and there is no `FullPath` property of `String`.

So there's no way that code could ever have worked with a non-modified version of the SharpSSH library.  You need to check if the version on the other computer where this supposedly worked was a modified version.